# How to test android app which requires two phones

Tags: android, android-testing

My android app is based upon communication between two android phones. But I posses only one android phone. An emulator cannot be used for testing. What are the alternates ? Do I have to purchase one more android phone ?

Comment: **"An emulator cannot be used for testing."** - Why not?

Comment: If you can't use an emulator, then you will have to use a physical device. It's that simple.

Comment: Please describe exactly what functionality do you require for the app so one can tell whether that is possible on emulator or not

Comment: i need two devices. my app in one device will send some data to my app in other device. even if i use emulator as one device how emulator, without any sim, can send data to my app in other mobile number ?